# Video is not visible in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to create an HTML5 web page and my video is not working safari.

here is the ss of the chrome browser

[image]

here is the ss of the safari browser
[image]

This is my HTML code

```
<video autoplay loop muted playsinline id="globe" preload="metadata" >
    <source src="assets/images/earth.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Js For autoplay video

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var herovide = document.getElementById('globe');
    herovide.autoplay=true;
    herovide.load();
});
```

Comment: Check the console to see if there's any errors. What codec has been used to create the video? Is it available in Safari?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I really appreciate your help, but there is no error in the console, My video is working properly in chrome but not visible in safari I don't know why it's happening

Comment: What version of Safari is it? Maybe you need to add webkit-playsinline next to playsinline

Comment: I'm watching my site on iPad Pro let me try with this one webkit-playsinlin

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan webkit-playsinline not working for me